# how to set a jvm flag in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I develop a gae app using tasks queue.

I m in development mode and i want to disable automatic execution of tasks.So i need to set the following flag:

> --jvm_flag=-Dtask_queue.disable_auto_task_execution=true

What i do is go to `run -> configurations-> arguments->` and then in the VM arguments I add the line.What i get as a result when i m trying to runt he app is :

> Unrecognized option:
>   --jvm_flag=-Dtask_queue.disable_auto_task_execution=true

Anybody has an idea how to set the flag properly?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
-Dtask_queue.disable_auto_task_execution=true
```

You don't need the "--jvm_flag=" in this case through eclipse.